# How to do I display the balance between two different sets of data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

[image]
I want to create a new table view cell on a different tableviewcontroller that will display the balance between income and expense data. How can I take the sum of income data and expense data, subtract expenses from income, then connect that balance to a UILabel in a new cell?

Here's how my project is laid out:

1. IncomeTableViewController - scene where incomes are listed.
2. AddEditIncomeTableViewController - scene that allows user to create new income.
3. IncomeTableViewCell - has custom cell. One UILabel for income name and another UILabel for the income amount.
4. ExpenseTableViewController - scene where expenses are listed.
5. AddEditExpenseTableViewController - scene that allows user to create new expense.
6. ExpenseTableViewCell - has custom cell. One UILabel for expense name and another UILabel for the expense amount.

```
import Foundation

struct Expense: Codable {
    var name: String
    var amount: String

    init(name: String, amount: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount

    }

    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

       static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("expenses").appendingPathExtension("plist")

       static func loadSampleExpenses() -> [Expense] {
           return [
                Expense(name: "Rent/Mortgage", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Electric", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Gas", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Cell Phone", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Groceries", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Car Payment", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Auto Expenses", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Auto Insurance", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Personal Care", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Entertainment", amount: "0"),
                Expense(name: "Miscellaneous", amount: "0")]
       }

       static func saveToFile(expenses: [Expense]) {
              let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
              let codedExpenses = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(expenses)

              try? codedExpenses?.write(to: ArchiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)

       }

       static func loadFromFile() -> [Expense]? {
               guard let codedExpenses = try? Data(contentsOf: ArchiveURL) else { return nil }

               let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()

               return try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Expense>.self, from: codedExpenses)
       }

   }
```

```
import Foundation

struct Income: Codable {
    var name: String
    var amount: String

    init(name: String, amount: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }



    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("incomes").appendingPathExtension("plist")

    static func loadSampleIncomes() -> [Income] {
        return [
            Income(name: "Main Income", amount: "0"),
            Income(name: "Secondary Income", amount: "0"),
            Income(name: "Interest Income", amount: "0")]

    }

    static func saveToFile(incomes: [Income]) {
           let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
           let codedIncomes = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(incomes)

           try? codedIncomes?.write(to: ArchiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)

    }

    static func loadFromFile() -> [Income]? {
            guard let codedIncomes = try? Data(contentsOf: ArchiveURL) else { return nil }

            let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()

            return try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Income>.self, from: codedIncomes)
    }

}
```

I also have these two files where I define Expense and Income. Not sure what code is necessary to show.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly u want to have a shared model to hold the data, so you can read and write data from and to the model from different UIViewControllers.

the easiest way to do so is using a singleton.

Comment: I don't really care if I have a shared model or not. I just want to take both income amount data and expense amount data presented as the balance between the two. I'm not sure how to

Comment: where do you hold the income and expense data?